# How to generate count query with the same EntityGraph than the findAll method

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to implement a pagination infrastructure with Spring Data JPA Specification, findAll and count methods. My domain model defines a ManyToOne(optional = true) association between Sale and Customer entities, as not all the sales have a customer. Additioinally, the domain model defines a named EntityGraph like this:

@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Sale.Customer", attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode(value = "customer"))

When I invoke the repository method findAll(Specification), the sql is using a left join from sale to customer because of the EntityGraph:

*select s1_0.nCabTicPky,s1_0.nCodTic,c1_0.nCodCli,c1_0.cCodCli,c1_0.cNomEmp from tcabtic s1_0 **left** join tclient c1_0 on c1_0.nCodCli=s1_0.nCodCli where s1_0.fFecTic like '%20%' limit ?,?*

When I invoke the repository method count(Specification), the sql is something like this:

*select count(s1_0.nCabTicPky) from tcabtic s1_0 **join** tclient c1_0 on c1_0.nCodCli=s1_0.nCodCli where s1_0.fFecTic like '%20%'*

As not all the sales have a customer assigned, the count query is returning only the count of sales with customer.

The project is using Spring Boot 3.0.5 and Hibernate 6.1.7.Final.

I've been struggling with this for several hours and can't see how to solve it. I've tried to implement a custom count method in my repository where I define the join as a left one, but this is ignored always. I've tried a count query with a subselect providing the proper EntityGraph as a query hint too.

I'd like some way to have the count of the records matching the criteria.